# Connection closed to child 0 with unclean shutdown (server domain.com:443)

Tags: ssl, loglevel

I just enbled `Loglevel debug` and am seeing this error frequently on our visitor traffic.  After some googling I'm not really able to determine what it means or what I should do about it... can anyone provide some advice?

```
Connection closed to child 0 with unclean shutdown (server www.domain.com:443)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL encryption protocol calls for a "clean" shutdown using specific messages to indicate the end of the connection.

In some cases the connection is just killed without the proper "goodbye" messages.  Unless your clients are experiencing problems, this is harmless.

Comment: Not necessarily harmless, just usually.